# Discovery papers for Uranus and Neptune

Tags: solar-system, history, neptune, uranus, resource-request

I would like to have the discovery papers, notices or announcements done by Herschel with Uranus and Le Verrier with Neptune. I know that Herschel adressed the Royal Society and Le Verrier sent some letters to other european astronomers, but I would like to have the first announcement source if those are available somewhere.

Comment: Might try "History of Science and Mathematics" stack if you don't get an answer here.

Comment: @antlersoft that's a good idea. I still have two unanswered astronomy-like questions there that I might move back here though! [How did Cassini measure the “Cassini state” of the Moon? What measurements were made; what did the data look like?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/8443/3869) and [Where can I find Lagrange’s original equilateral triangular solution for arbitrary masses?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/11781/3869)